# Customise donut chart provided by google charts js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: required-donut-chart]

I want to use a donut chart  using jgoogle charts:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#making-a-donut-chart

```
 <html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript"   src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieHole: 0.4,
         };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="donutchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem I am facing is as to how to show one part of the donut a bit thicker as compared to others; i.e. as depicted in the attached image - ("required-donut-chart"). Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#making-a-donut-chart), I don't think that's possible.

You can set an offset for each 'slice' in the donut-chart, but this won't affect the thickness:

```
var options = {
  title: 'My Daily Activities',
  pieHole: 0.4,
  slices: {0: {offset: 0.5}}, // positions the first slice out from the center
};
```

Comment: Yes, offset would just shift the slice. I wanted to know if there are any options to alter the width..Thanks between for your response.

Comment: Can any other free chart js libraries provide such customisation?